# Can't load images while SignalR is connected on Mobile Safari

Tags: connection, mobile-safari, signalr

Since Mobile Safari enforces a 'one connection per server' limit, my web page cannot load any images while SignalR is running. SignalR is being used to show real-time comments on the page, but some comments contain images and on Mobile Safari those images fail to load as SignalR is using the connection.

The images load in real-time as expected on other browsers.

Unfortunately I don't have any other domains / subdomains I could serve from. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to be a known issue that has been thoroughly discussed here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1406